# Making Image Divs responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make the Images in "fullwidthbanner" as fully responsive. May be the problem is that it has two images which I want it to transform with size.

### This is my HTML

```
<div class="main-container col1-layout">
    <div class="main row-second clearfix">

        <div class="col-main">
              <div class="std"><div class="sub-container"><div class="fullwidthbanner-container">
                  <div class="fullwidthbanner>

                      <div class="item"><img src="http://127.0.0.1/www/media/wysiwyg/sub-head1.jpg" alt="Random Collection"></div>
                      <div class="item"><img src="http://127.0.0.1/www/media/wysiwyg/sub-head1.jpg" alt="Random Collection"></div>
                  </div>
              </div> 
        </div>
    </div>                
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.sub-container {overflow:auto;}
.main-container {background:#fafafa; }
.main { margin:0 auto; position: relative; z-index:1; }

.sub-container div.item{ background-color:red; float:left;}
.sub-container div.item:hover{ background-color:green;}
.sub-container div.item img{ width:100% !important; display:block;}
```

For some reason, it does everything I want it to, but both the Images are fully extending in terms of width. The width always remain the same and when the window size increases, it just shows an empty space in front of both images.

Comment: You have divs `.sub-container` and `.fullwidthbanner-container`, which you evidently forgot about -- they aren't closed. Also `.fullwidthbanner` has a missing double quote.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui Let's keep religion out of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is the html:

```
<div class="main-container col1-layout">
  <div class="main row-second clearfix">
    <div class="col-main">
      <div class="std">
        <div class="sub-container">
          <div class="fullwidthbanner-container">
            <div class="fullwidthbanner">
              <div class="item">
                <img src="http://127.0.0.1/www/media/wysiwyg/sub-head1.jpg" alt="Eid Collection" />
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <img src="http://127.0.0.1/www/media/wysiwyg/sub-head1.jpg" alt="Eid Collection" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>                
    </div>
  </div>                
</div>
```

Does this css do what you want?

```
.sub-container div.item {
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Although I would suggest using `max-width`, instead of `width` -- this will make it adapt to smaller screens, and on larger screens it won't get blurry.